# XML from Server to populate a Spinner

Tags: android, xml, json, spinner

I would like for the spinner to be populated from a server's MySQL, the website is PHP and can be formated to send an XML or JSON file.

Is there a way to populate the spinner with that information? I can save the file to memory, but how can I read it on the spinner?

Should the file be save as a Preferences file and then read that way?

Any help will be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Folks;

After lots of looking and trying and testing and doing hundread of other things I answered my own question.

This is something that may be a Doh! answer for programmers, but I am not a programmer, I am learning and doing this as a school project, so my knowledge of Java is not even enought to be called "basic".

This is the answer to my own question;

```
String CountryName = preferences.getString("country name", null);
List<String> lCounties = Arrays.asList(Counties(CountryName).split(","));
CharSequence[] csCounties = lCounties.toArray(new CharSequence[lCounties.size()]);

final Spinner sCounty = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.county);    
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> aCounty = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(
        this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,csCounties);
aCounty.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
sCounty.setAdapter(aCounty);
sCounty.setSelection(preferences.getInt("county",0));
sCounty.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3){
      int iCounty = sCounty.getSelectedItemPosition();
      String CountyName = sCountry.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
      editor.putString("county name", CountyName);
      editor.putInt("county", iCounty);
      editor.commit();

      //Refresh Page is county has changed
      if (oCounty != iCounty){ refresh(); }
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}
  });
```

Now this is the explanation (as far as I undertand...)

First I read the country from another spinner (I have 'few' spinners joined together)

```
String CountryName = preferences.getString("country name", null);
```

Then I use this information to call a subclass (I can publish this too). This subclass contacts the server to create a MySQL query an retrieves the needed information; in this case the counties (or states) for a given country, the list is received as state1,state2,state3, [this was formated on the PHP on the server to help]

```
List<String> lCounties = Arrays.asList(Counties(CountryName).split(","));
CharSequence[] csCounties = lCounties.toArray(new CharSequence[lCounties.size()]);
```

The next lines of code are the actual Spinner, there is alot of information about spinner on the net, so I will not explain much of this.

The spinner read the saved information using this line;

```
sCounty.setSelection(preferences.getInt("county",0));
```

this allows the spinner to be pre-populated with the users choice.

Then I store the selection, I store both the name and pointer. The name is saved to complete the URL when the page is loaded and the pointer is saved bacuase the Spinner seems to like pointers.

```
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
  editor.putString("county name", CountyName);
  editor.putInt("county", iCounty);
  editor.commit();
```

The last thing I do is a comparison, the varible `oCounty` is read when the page loads, it simply reads the `preference` file and stores the value on `oCounty` (Original County), if the county name changes, then it calls `refresh()`, this subclass refreshes the page. [This too was a pain to put together for me]

```
  //Refresh Page is county has changed
  if (oCounty != iCounty){ refresh(); }
```

The way the whole thing works now is that once a country is selected from the list, the page goes to the server, loads the counties/states for the country and refreshed the page, thus loading the values on the spinner, if the country changes, the process will load the counties/states again.

The same code is used with the counties/states to load the cities, I jsut changed the variable's names.

I am sure programmers have a nicer, faster, quicker way to do this, but these are my 2 cents on how to populate spinners with iformation stored on a MySQL database on the server.

Regards;
Ramón

Answer (score 0):

First parse your XMl or JSON. then create a list or array of the data which will be shown in spinner. pass the data to the adapter of the spinner.

### Example

```
Spinner sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnContactTypes);

        String numbers[] = { "ONE", "TWO" }; // data that you got from xml or JSON
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter; = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, numbers);
        sp.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: the problem is how do I parse the information onto the String? Your answer "hard codes" the numbers (ONE and TWO) to the string, it does not use the SERVER information to populate the string, and that is what I am trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Spinner can be populated from the output of the parsed `XML`/`JSON`

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Map.this.getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, HERE-GOES-PARSED-ARRAY-OF-JSON-or-XML);
                        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        spin.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Same as the answer before, you are giving me what I have, I am looking for the code needed to parse the server information onto the HERE-GOES-PARSED-ARRAY-OF-JSON-or_XML; how do I accomplish that??

Answer (score -1):

**Back-end**

This consists of the Mysql Database and Webserver.

Summary steps to follow:

1. Create a mysql database
2. Create a configuration file to make a connection between our database and web server(php)
3. Create a php script which will house the method that will query the database visit the link below.

**Front-end**

1. Create activity_main.xml , add TextView and Spinner controls in activity_main.xml.
2. Open MainActivity class,Create Android path to the server with a request method that connects with            the server to obtain the server output and convert it to the response�s object.
3. Creating a java file to serve as an entity class to hold spinner items.
4. Creating a custom BaseAdapter to bind the remote data source with the spinner items.
5. Adjusting Gradle Build,to include projectdependencies in the app gradle.build.
6. Adjust Manifest.xml file to include Manifest.xml file user permissions-Explained for internet to make a            network call since application needs internet.Read full example:[How to load android spinner with php mysql database values](http://byronetsystems.com/-SOLVED-How-to-load-Android-spinner-with-mysql-database-values.php)